# Binary negation in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I can't seem to find logical negation of integers as an operator anywhere in Python.

Currently I'm using this:

```
def not_(x):
    assert x in (0, 1)
    return abs(1-x)
```

But I feel a little stupid.  Isn't there a built-in operator for this?  The logical negation (`not`) returns a Boolean -- that's not really what I want.  Is there a different operator, or a way to make `not` return an integer, or am I stuck with this dodgy workaround?

Comment: In fact, Python's bool derives from int... try `isinstance(True, int)` :)

Comment: what is the reason for the `abs` here? if you're asserting `x in (0,1)` then `abs` won't do anything right, or did you mean to write `int` to handle the case where `x` was a float?

Comment: @wim: yeah, you're right, it doesn't do anything.  i think that was there before the assert made it into the code.  thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: thank you everybody for your comments and answers.  i forgot that in python one can cast boolean to int -- i think that is the simplest way to do things.

Comment: you can try `~` operator, it shall work just fine: `~x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
int(not(x))
```

? Assuming that any non-zero integer value is true and 0 is false you'll always get integer 0 or 1 as a result.

Comment: be careful that `x` is always initialised, since `int(not(None))` is `1`

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
int(not x)
```

to convert the boolean to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 3):

If what you expect is to get 1 when input is 0, and 0 and when input is 1, then XOR is your friend. You need to XOR your value with 1:

```
negate = lambda x: x ^ True
    
negate(0)
Out: 1

negate(1)
Out: 0

negate(False)
Out: True

negate(True)
Out: False
```

Comment: -1 for named lambda function. In addition, I don't think the XOR is the clearest solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for Bitwise Not, then `~` is what you are looking for. However, it works in the two's complement form.

Answer (score 1):

This will raise a KeyError if x is not in (0,1)

```
def not_(x):
    return {1:0,0:1}[x]
```

The tuple version would also accept -1 if you don't add a check for it, but is probably faster

```
def not_(x):
    return (1,0)[x]

$ python -m timeit "(1,0)[0]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0629 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "(1,0)[1]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0646 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "1^1"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.063 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "1^0"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0638 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "int(not(0))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.354 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "int(not(1))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.354 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "{1:0,0:1}[0]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.446 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "{1:0,0:1}[1]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.443 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not` but then convert result to integer.

```
int(False)
0
int(True)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Your approach is very good for two reasons:

1. It is fast, clear and understandable
2. It does error-checking

I assume that there cannot be such operator defined on the integers, because of the following problem: what to return if given value is not 0 or 1? Throw exception? Assume positive integers to mean 1? But negative integers?

Your approach defines concrete behaviour - accept only 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using some basic binary and string manipulation features in python

> if x be an integer for which we want a bitwise negation, which is
> called x_bar(learned in digital class :))

```
>>> x_bar = x^int('1'*len(bin(x).split('b')[1]),2)
>>> bin(x_bar) #returns the binary string representation of integer 'x'
```

bin(int_value) function returns the binary string representation of any integer eg: '0b11011011'

xor operation is done with '1's'